# Check if 2 string are differents java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a problem with a if condition, I have this code :

```
if(!session.getAttribute("login").equals(d3.getLogin_demandeur())){
    //do something
}else{
    //do something else
}
```

So with this code if `session.getAttribute("login")` is equals to `d3.getLogin_demandeur()` it should go to the else statement, but this doesn't work, I have printed out these 2 values and they are the same and this still go to the else statement, any idea ?

EDIT :

Here is how I print

```
System.out.println(session.getAttribute("login")+"="+(d3.getLogin_demandeur()));
```

And what I have :

```
smilleto=smilleto
```

Comment: Some space behind a string?

Comment: Show us their values, & the code where you print them.

Comment: `it should go to the else statement ...they are the same and this still go to the else statement` - isn't that the expected behavior?

Comment: i´d also recommend to read the values before you go into the if statement and check them for beeing `null` to prevent a `NPE`.

Comment: @Eran Well no, if they are equals this should go to the else statement with this code no ?

Comment: @SimonM. You wrote that it goes to the else statement - `and this still go to the else statement`.

Comment: try printing this `System.out.println(session.getAttribute("login").equals(d3.getLogin_demandeur()));` to the console & see whether it prints **true** of **false**.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG it returns me false but why ? If they look like the same in the output

Comment: @SimonM. you could do the following. Get the `char` array for both Strings, print theyr length and also compare the `int` representation of the `char`. Maybe you are having problems with a wrong formatting, have a 0-space character in between or you are having whitespaces at the end.

Comment: Can you try printing this
`System.out.println(session.getAttribute("login").toString().equals(d3.getLogin_demandeur()‌​));`

Comment: Please reconsider accepting my answer over @Sameer Mirji's, his answer is misleading to anyone searching for the same problem (altho it works as well, the reason is not valid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `trim()` function to remove any unwanted spaces and use `equalsIgnoreCase()` if you don't have case sensitivity as a criteria.

```
String login = (String)session.getAttribute("login").trim();
String loginDemandeur = d3.getLogin_demandeur().trim(); // Assuming getLogin_demandeur has return type as String. 
if(!login.equalsIgnoreCase(loginDemandeur)){
  //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

Comment: This is working because the attribute casting, not because the trimming.